# SVN pre-revprop-change error even after enabled and granted permission

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to edit my logs from windows client to Linux repository, I know by default svn doesn't permit this behavior so I created pre-revprop-change like this (I'll grant every edit ):

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0;
```

granted permission:

```
chmod +x pre-revprop-change
```

still I get this error:

```
SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: DAV request failed; it's possible that the
repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent ---> 
SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: At least one property change failed; repository is 
unchanged ---> SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: Error setting property 'log': 
Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook
```